# How can I troubleshoot the 'connection lost' error when trying to connect to Firebase using TSIM7600 and TinyGsmClient on Arduino IDE?

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, lte

I am using TSIM7600 na to take GPS data and transfer it to Firebase. I am programming in Arduino IDE with the FirebaseESP32 library to connect to the database and TinyGsmClient to connect to the LTE network. When I do them separately they work correctly but when I join them I get an error that says: connection lost.

```
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM7600
#define SerialAT Serial1
#define SerialMon Serial
#define TINY_GSM_DEBUG SerialMon

#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#include <FirebaseESP32.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <addons/TokenHelper.h>
#include <addons/RTDBHelper.h>

const char apn[] = "internet.cnt.net.ec";
const char gprsUser[] = "";
const char gprsPass[] = "";

#define PIN_TX 27
#define PIN_RX 26
#define UART_BAUD 115200
#define PWR_PIN 4
#define LED_PIN 12
#define POWER_PIN 25
#define DTR 32
#define RI 33
#define PMU_IRQ 35
#define IND_PIN 36

#define API_KEY ""
#define DATABASE_URL ""
#define USER_EMAIL ""
#define USER_PASSWORD ""

// Define Firebase Data object
FirebaseData fbdo;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseConfig config;

unsigned long sendDataPrevMillis = 0;
unsigned long count = 0;

#ifdef DUMP_AT_COMMANDS
#include <StreamDebugger.h>
StreamDebugger debugger(SerialAT, SerialMon);
TinyGsm modem(debugger);
#else
TinyGsm modem(SerialAT);
#endif

TinyGsmClient client(modem);

void setup() {
  SerialMon.begin(115200);

  Serial.printf("Firebase Client v%s\n\n", FIREBASE_CLIENT_VERSION);

  config.api_key = API_KEY;

  auth.user.email = USER_EMAIL;
  auth.user.password = USER_PASSWORD;

  config.database_url = DATABASE_URL;

  config.token_status_callback = tokenStatusCallback;  // see addons/TokenHelper.h
  Firebase.begin(&config, &auth);
  Firebase.setDoubleDigits(5);

  // Onboard LED light, it can be used freely
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);

  // POWER_PIN : This pin controls the power supply of the SIM7600
  pinMode(POWER_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(POWER_PIN, HIGH);

  pinMode(PWR_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(PWR_PIN, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(PWR_PIN, LOW);

  pinMode(IND_PIN, INPUT);
  DBG("Wait...");
  delay(3000);

  SerialAT.begin(UART_BAUD, SERIAL_8N1, PIN_RX, PIN_TX);

  DBG("Initializing modem...");
  if (!modem.init()) {
    DBG("Failed to restart modem, delaying 10s and retrying");
    return;
  }

  String result;
  result = modem.setNetworkMode(2);  //2 para automatico 38 solo para LTE
  if (modem.waitResponse(10000L) != 1) {
    DBG(" setNetworkMode faill");
    return;
  }

  String name = modem.getModemName();
  DBG("Modem Name:", name);
  String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();
  DBG("Modem Info:", modemInfo);
}

void loop() {
  SerialMon.print("Connecting to APN: ");
  SerialMon.print(apn);
  if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass)) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
  } else {
    SerialMon.println(" OK");

//Optencion de longitud y latitud
#if defined TINY_GSM_MODEM_HAS_GPS
    DBG("Enabling GPS/GNSS/GLONASS");
    modem.enableGPS();

    float lat2 = 0;
    float lon2 = 0;

    DBG("Requesting current GPS/GNSS/GLONASS location");
    for (;;) {
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, !digitalRead(LED_PIN));
      if (modem.getGPS(&lat2, &lon2)) {
        DBG("Latitude:", String(lat2 * -1, 8), "\tLongitude:", String(lon2, 8));
    
        }
        break;
      }
    }
#endif
    delay(5000);
    //aqui va la coneccion a FIREBASE

    //if (Firebase.ready() && (millis() - sendDataPrevMillis > 15000 || sendDataPrevMillis ==  0)) {
      
          sendDataPrevMillis = millis();
          Serial.printf("Set Lat... %s\n", Firebase.setFloat(fbdo, F("/test/Lat"), 1055.2) ? "ok" : fbdo.errorReason().c_str());
          Serial.printf("Set Lon... %s\n", Firebase.setFloat(fbdo, F("/test/Lon"), 55.2) ? "ok" : fbdo.errorReason().c_str());

          count++;

  //}
}
```

When trying to send via WIFI there is no problem but with LTE I get that error as the connection was lost and it does not connect to Firebase